# What is the fate of a thermal fluctuations in the early universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology

So I tried googling this but couldn't find anything.

My understanding the early universe was in thermal equilibrium. Now, there must have been [thermal fluctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_fluctuations) then as well. Given in the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) the covariant volume would have expanded. What becomes of these fluctuated patches become? Naively, I'd expect them to expand as well. Surely they must lead to some observational features?

Answer (score -1):

They are the seeds that eventually grow into the structure we observe today. This is the science of "structure formation": how the tiny fluctuations that we observe in the Cosmic Microwave Background grow into the huge fluctuations we observe today with galaxies.

Comment: I believe those are quantum fluctuations though?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation